# How to return variable and value from function for future use?

Tags: python, function

```
def os_check():
    if os.name == 'nt':
        write_file = r'D:\text.txt'
        return write_file
    else:
        write_file = '/folder/txttt.txt'
        return  write_file

os_check()

print(write_file)
```

When I try to return variable I have error:

> NameError: name 'write_file' is not defined

How to return in properly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Return possibly not returning value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53347740/python-return-possibly-not-returning-value)

Comment: You don't return *variabls* you return *objects*. Your `os_check()` call returned that object, but you didn't assign it to anything, therefore the result is discarded, you needed something like `write_file = os_check()`, or any other variable, `foo = os_check()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to assign a value to a new variable

```
import  os
def os_check():
    if os.name == 'nt':
        write_file = r'D:\text.txt'
        return write_file
    else:
        write_file = '/folder/txttt.txt'
        return write_file

write_file = os_check()  # <--- here

print(write_file)
```